# LARAVEL Migrate ERROR SQLSTATE[42000] "exist in table"

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, migration, migrate

I get an error when running the artisan migrate

first is I want to run for a relationship Many-to-Many and add a table to the relationship many-to-many and what happened when I migrate is the error appears on the terminal.

```
    [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                         
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1072 Key column 'hobi' d  
  oesn't exist in table (SQL: alter table `hobi_siswa` add constraint `hobi_s  
  iswa_hobi_foreign` foreign key (`hobi`) references `hobi` (`id`) on delete   
  cascade on update cascade)                                                   



  [PDOException]                                                               
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1072 Key column 'hobi' d  
  oesn't exist in table
```

it was said terminal, but I was surprised and confused as to why could equally padahah its purpose is key relations.

```
  <?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateTableHobiSiswa extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        //create table hobi siswa
        Schema::create('hobi_siswa', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('id_siswa')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->integer('id_hobi')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->timestamps();

            //set PK
            $table->primary(['id_siswa', 'id_hobi']);

            //set FK hobi siswa --- siswa
            $table->foreign('id_siswa')
                  ->references('id')
                  ->on('hobi')
                  ->onDelete('cascade')
                  ->onUpdate('cascade');

            //Set FK Hobi_siswa ---hobi
            $table->foreign('hobi')
                  ->references('id')
                  ->on('hobi')
                  ->onDelete('cascade')
                  ->onUpdate('cascade');
        });

    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('hobi_siswa');
    }
}
```

and it is createTableHobiSiswa I do what I want to migrate

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateTableHobi extends Migration
{

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('hobi', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('nama_hobi');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('hobi');
    }
}
```

and this is wanting in relation createTableHobi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like the value you have given to `foreign()` in your 2nd foreign key chain references the column `hobi`, when the column on the table is actually `id_hobi`.

Try changing this part:

```
//Set FK Hobi_siswa ---hobi
$table->foreign('hobi')
      ->references('id')
      ->on('hobi')
      ->onDelete('cascade')
      ->onUpdate('cascade');
```

To this instead:

```
//Set FK Hobi_siswa ---hobi
$table->foreign('id_hobi') //reference the column on this table correctly
      ->references('id')
      ->on('hobi')
      ->onDelete('cascade')
      ->onUpdate('cascade');
```